# Draw a path in Gephi using pytjon script beween two random nodes

Tags: python, node.js, random, path

I want to draw a path between two random nodes in Gephi. I write my sudo code please help me.

```
import random

i = random.sample(g.nodes,1) #[v76]  head of path
j = random.sample(g.nodes,1) #[v71]  end of path
# i = random.randint(n)      #first node, head of path
# j = random.randint(n)      #second node, end of path
for u in g.nodes:
    head = i
    for v in g.nodes:
        g.addUndirectedEdge(head,v);
        head = v;
        if v==j: break
```

**Result:**

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>   
TypeError: addDirectedEdge(): 1st arg can't be coerced to org.gephi.scripting.wrappers.GyNode
```

Comment: The complete code is:
import random

i=random.sample(g.nodes,1) //[v76] head of path

j=random.sample(g.nodes,1) //[v71] end of path

//i=random.randint(n) //first node, head of path

//j=random.randint(n) //second node, end of path

for u in g.nodes:

    head=i
            for v in g.nodes:
                    g.addUndirectedEdge(head,v);
                    head=v;
                    if v==j:
                            break

Comment: how is this related to `node.js` tag?